# Can you compare an array of strings in PHP and if there are two that are the same it will only return it once?

Tags: php

Here is the script I am running and I would like if there are 2 strings that the same to only display one string and not both. I dont know where to add the array_unique() I have added it to my script but it doesnt seem to work properlly, instead it is taking out all the strings with the same value   Here is the script I am running and I would like if there are 2 strings that the same to only display one string and not both

```
//Get slider data from theme options
$company1 = $data['md_media_company_img1'];
$company2 = $data['md_media_company_img2'];
$company3 = $data['md_media_company_img3'];
$company4 = $data['md_media_company_img4'];
$company5 = $data['md_media_company_img5'];
$company6 = $data['md_media_company_img6'];
$company7 = $data['md_media_company_img7'];
$company8 = $data['md_media_company_img8'];
$company9 = $data['md_media_company_img9'];
$company10 = $data['md_media_company_img10'];
$company11 = $data['md_media_company_img11'];
$company12 = $data['md_media_company_img12'];

/*Slides Array*/
$company_name = array( 
    'company1' => array(
        'name' => $company1,
    ),
    'company2' => array(
        'name' => $company2,
    ),
    'company3' => array(
        'name' => $company3,
    ),
    'company4' => array(
        'name' => $company4,
    ),
    'company5' => array(
        'name' => $company5,
    ),
    'company6' => array(
        'name' => $company6,
    ),
    'company7' => array(
        'name' => $company7,
    ),
    'company8' => array(
        'name' => $company8,
    ),
    'company9' => array(
        'name' => $company9,
    ),
    'company10' => array(
        'name' => $company10,
    ),
    'company11' => array(
        'name' => $company11,
    ),
    'company12' => array(
        'name' => $company12,
    )

);

/*check if exist slide*/
$check_exist_company = 0;
$result = array_unique($company_name);
foreach($result as $company => $value) {
    if (!empty ($value['name'])){
        $check_exist_company = 1;
    }
}
```

?>

```
            <?php if($check_exist_company == 1) {// check if any slide image added in theme option, return custom slide?>
                <?php $i = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach($company_name as $company => $value) {

                        if (!empty ($value['name'])) {?>

                            <li><a class="nivoLink4" rel="<?php echo $i;?>" href="#"><?php echo $value['name'];?></a></li>
                             <?php ++$i ?>

                            <?php } ?>
                      <?php }?>

            <?php } ?>

<!--/slider-->
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just run array_unique() on the source array and just iterate over the result.

Comment: I have tried using array_unique() and for some reason it isnt working. I edited my code with the whole script I have created, maybe you can tell me where to place it in my code. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing in your array that's unique, every value in there is different.